# Ruby how to force output 0 when count has no rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@counseling = Counseling.ransack(params[:q])
@counselings = @counseling.result.joins('RIGHT JOIN "subjects" ON "subjects"."id" = "counselings"."subject_id"')
@result = {}
@result[:data] = @counselings.group(row_condition).count
```

> Blockquote

```
def self.create_case_sql_for_nested_tree2(foreign_key)
    modelClass = foreign_key.sub(/_id3$/, '').camelize.constantize
    @when_then_conditions = modelClass.roots.map do |o|
      o.children.map do |c|
        c.children.map do |g|
        idlist = g.self_and_descendants.pluck(:id)
        "WHEN subject_id IN(#{idlist.join(',')}) THEN #{g.id}"
        end
      end
    end
    "CASE #{@when_then_conditions.join(' ')} ELSE null END"
end
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about your problem. Because count normally return 0 if no row found.

Comment: select s.id, count(nullif(subject_id,0)) AS count from counselings c right join subjects s on c.subject_id=s.id group by s.id order by s.id;

Comment: when I execute the above sql the output shows the record with 0 count But i dont know how to implement the same in ruby.

Comment: If you want to count the number of `counselings` why you need it to join with `subject` model?

Comment: yes, I don't need subject model for getting the counts of subjects in counselings but my project need it that way . I am using ransack don't know how to get the rows who has null in subject field of counselings. Count function is ignoring the nulls. But I want it to show 0 count.

Comment: Nullif is working in sql but not in ruby.

Comment: Thanks hashrocket ‼️

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, You want to join `Counseling` and `Subject` model and count the `subject_id`. I think you can do it like this,

```
Counseling.joins(:subject).count(:subject_id)
```

If you want to put any where condition you can do it like this,

```
Counseling.joins(:subject).where("some condition").count(:subject_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you can see in my sql I want to do count on the field subject_id of counseling model but want to group by it with subject model subjectid field.  Thats why i am using CASE sql.

Comment: Problem is I dont know how to do RIGHT JOIN. when we use joins(:subject) it does inner join. And i need count function to count null rows. I dont think there is any function like nullif in ruby to do that.count(:subject_id) is going to do count of all not null rows.